# "price on" and "price for"

Tags: prepositions

In Insider Secrets To Hydraulics book there are two sentences with **price** in it:

> 1) Befor the distributor can quote you **a price on** an equivalent pump, a sales engineer has to identify all the specifications of the existing unit, such as shaft, mounting, ports and displacement, and then cross-reference this information to find a suitable alternative.
>
> 2) Assuming **the price for** the 'Brand-Y' pump is cheaper than the price you were quoted for the 'Brand-X' unit and the two brands are similar in quality, you can use this as leverage to get a better deal from the 'Brand-X' distributor.

Can you explain to me why in 1) there is construction with preposition "on" and  in 2) there is construction with preposition "for".

Comment: The first is “quote (a price) on”...the second is “the price for” something.

Comment: 'Of' is probably the most used preposition here, but preference is context-dependent. 'A price on' connotes 'a price set/levied on' (probably not the actual words) and is more seller-orientated. 'The price for' is nuanced less towards the involvement of the seller, and more towards the product (or even buyer). The price for it / for me to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context and in idiomatic English "**on**" and "**for**" are interchangeable. There is little or no difference. By convention a quotation is often spoken of as "**a price on**" and when talking about the cost of an item it is "**the price for**" but there is no rule governing this. It would be quite acceptable to ask

> "Would you please quote me the price for that job?"

Then again it is more conventional to ask for "**a** price on" but talk about "**the** price for".

There is also the perfectly acceptable "the / a price **of**..." which can be used in either context. "Quote the price of a pump" and "The price of a pump is ..."